# how to read from excel to matlab and use the information to find some variables

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an excel file that contains information about conductors.
eg:

```
type     r        GMR      R
-------- -------- -------- -------- 
b        0.773    0.604    0.238    
c        0.815    0.6614   0.235    
d        0.864    0.698    0.209
```

I want to write a Matlab program to read these values then display a message 'type of conductor? '

then takes the values from the desired row and uses it to find some values.
eg:

```
If b was chosen i want to find x=ln(r)=ln(.773)  and y=GMR^2 ...
if c was chosen x=ln(0.815)
```

I know how to write a program that can read form a single row or column but not a whole sheet.

Comment: @Mohammed: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn about interacting with this community of programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html)

> `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename)`
>   reads data from the first worksheet in
>   the Microsoft Excel spreadsheet file
>   named filename and returns the numeric
>   data in array num. Optionally, returns
>   the text fields in cell array txt, and
>   the unprocessed data (numbers and
>   text) in cell array raw.
>
> `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,sheet)` reads the
>   specified worksheet.

So here's an example program which reads `foo.xls` into the numeric matrix `D` and the text info `txt`.

```
%# Read the XLS file
[D txt] = xlsread('foo.xls');
%# Assume the columns are fixed (if not see note 3)
r_col = 1; gmr_col = 2;
%# Get the type of conductor
cond = inputdlg('type of conductor?');
%# Search for the right row
index = strcmp(txt(2:end,1),cond);
%# Compute the data
x = log(D(index,r_col));
y = D(index,gmr_col).^2;
```

#### Note:

1. If you don't want a dialog box, replace `inputdlg` with `input`
2. If there are multiple rows with the same `type` value, then `x` and `y` will be vectors
3. I'm assuming that `r` and `GMR` are columns 1 and 2 respectively. If you don't know this, you can find out by using `strcmp` on the first row of `txt`. I.e.,

   ```
   r_col   = strcmp(txt(1,:),'r');
   gmr_col = strcmp(txt(1,:),'GMR');
   ```

Comment: I already know that,
but what I'm looking for is:once the matrix is generated (after xlsread)
I want the program to display 'type of conductor?'
then one row will be chosen, 
then I want the program to deal with every element in this row separately.

Comment: @Jacop
thank you so much but one last question:
`[D txt] = xlsread('ACSR.xls');
r_col = 1; gmr_col = 2; R_col=3;
cond = inputdlg('type of conductor?');
index = strcmp(txt(2:end,1),cond);
Deq= inputdlg('what is Deq?');
disp(Deq);
C = (2*pi*(8.85*10^-12))./(log(Deq./(D(index,r_col))));
L= (2*10^-7)*(log(Deq./(D(index,gmr_col))));
R= D(index,R_col);`
that is the actual program but it says that there is an error:

??? Undefined function or method 'rdivide' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> RLC at 12
C = (2*pi*(8.85*10^-12))./(log(Deq./(D(index,r_col))));

Comment: @Mohammed: You need to get an index for `Deq` as well. As you can see, you get the text input `cond` and find the index `index`. Similarly, you obtain text input `Deq` and so you need to find the index corresponding to `Deq` with `strcmp`. Do you understand the code? If not, let me know.

Comment: @Jacop: I know that it compares the two arguments and give a logic 0 & 1 ,but how would this help me.
the problem is that **Deq** is a cell type and I can't use it in multiplication or division.

I know that you are probably tiered from my questions but that is the problem with students.